# Forzar a 0 un funcion quadratica en lmer

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando en `lmer` en R. Tengo dudas si hay formas de poner un término quadratico (como factor fijo) forzando al origen esta relación. Actualmente estoy usando `(poly(x,degree=2,raw=TRUE))`, pero esta no es forzado a 0:0. Es posible realizar esto?

El modelo es el siguiente:
`model<-lmer(Y~a+b+(poly(x,degree=2,raw=TRUE))+(1|factor_aleatorio), data=data)`

Comment: Ayudaría escribir la llamada a 'lmer (Y ~ ....)` para entender la pregunta. Además si X es numérico, la cuadrática forzada, sería `Y ~ x + I(x^2) - 1`

Answer (score 0):

En la fórmula `Y ~ ....` del modelo puedes forzar a cero eliminando el intercepto poniendo el término `Y ~ .... - 1` o bien `Y ~ .... + 0`

Comment: Marcelo, muchas gracias. Ahi edite mi pregunta. Lo que necesito es que la funcion cuadratica este forzada a 0, pero el intercepto del modelo general no lo sea. Es posible?

Comment: Las fórmulas `Y~a+b+(poly(x,degree=2,raw=TRUE))+(1|factor_aleatorio)` y `Y~a+b+x+I(x^2)+(1|factor_aleatorio)` dan el mismo resultado. Prueba `Y~a+b+x+I(x^2) + 0 + (1|factor_aleatorio)` que estaría considerando que el intercepto es aleatorio. Prueba ver `model.matrix( model )`. Así estarías ajustando la función cuadrática sin termino constante. En ese caso la esperanza del modelo cuando x=0 serían factores fijos a y b.